# How do I display the value of an object

Tags: java, android, android-studio

How can I get the value of the object@notificationTextParams[0].id as a string?
[image: Debug]

Comment: `SimpleGeofence` should override the `toString` method. And what would it mean for you to print its value? I see a lot of fields in that object. What would you print?

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca, I'm simply trying to print, in this example "DNA Styles"

Comment: Ok, but we have no idea what the `SimpelGeofence` class is. If it's a class you wrote, see the duplicate target about how to implement the `toString` method. If it's not a class you made, maybe it has a `getId` method that returns just that?

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca simpleGeofence.getId() was my original attempt but it returns null.  There's a string variable called 'foo' that I used to verify that. Yet as best as I can tell, it has a value. See screenshot...
https://imgur.com/a/hOXkTK7

Answer (score -2):

```
@Override
public String toString(){
return **whatever you**
```

This way you override the standard toString method printing the allocated data location.